# where is cygwin's wget

Tags: cygwin, wget

Did wget move to a package?  I use to use setup.exe and search for `wget` to install it.  I don't see it anymore.

The `net` package is already installed.  Both attempts to run `wget` and `locate wget` turn up nothing.

Comment: This is better posted on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` is its own package -> http://cygwin.com/packages/wget/

```
$ cygcheck -f $( which wget )
wget-1.13.4-1
```

Comment: setup.exe was pointed to local files.  it needed to be re-directed back to the Internet mirror.

Answer (score 8):

## If you have Chocolatey

Just installs [cyg-get](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get):

```
choco install cyg-get
```

Then:

```
cyg-get install wget
```

Comment: Never knew about Chocolatey -- this is awesome

Comment: It would be even more awesome if it worked, lol. It appears to be trying to install Cygwin from scratch, and then failing to match setup-x86_64.exe's SHA256 checksum.